# Reading a binary file 1 byte at a time

Tags: c, file, io, binary

I am trying to read a binary file in C 1 byte at a time and after searching the internet for hours I still can not get it to retrieve anything but garbage and/or a seg fault. Basically the binary file is in the format of a list that is 256 items long and each item is 1 byte (an unsigned int between 0 and 255). I am trying to use fseek and fread to jump to the "index" within the binary file and retrieve that value. The code that I have currently:

```
unsigned int buffer;

int index = 3; // any index value

size_t indexOffset = 256 * index;
fseek(file, indexOffset, SEEK_SET);
fread(&buffer, 256, 1, file);

printf("%d\n", buffer);
```

Right now this code is giving me random garbage numbers and seg faulting. Any tips as to how I can get this to work right?

Comment: Reading a file one byte at a time would incur massive I/O overhead.  A better approach would be to read the entire file into a buffer (since it is only 256 bytes) and process each byte stored in the buffer individually.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy - I believe the I/O Manager will buffer the reads on modern operating systems.

Answer (score 18):

Your confusing *bytes* with *int*.  The common term for a *byte* is an *unsigned char*.  Most bytes are 8-bits wide.  If the data you are reading is 8 bits, you will need to read in 8 bits:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

/* Read in 256 8-bit numbers into the buffer */
size_t bytes_read = 0;
bytes_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BUFFER_SIZE, file_ptr);
// Note: sizeof(unsigned char) is for emphasis
```

The reason for reading all the data into memory is to keep the I/O flowing.  There is an overhead associated with each input request, regardless of the quantity requested.  Reading one byte at a time, or seeking to one position at a time is the worst case.

Here is an example of the overhead required for reading 1 byte:

```
Tell OS to read from the file.
OS searches to find the file location.
OS tells disk drive to power up.
OS waits for disk drive to get up to speed.
OS tells disk drive to position to the correct track and sector.
-->OS tells disk to read one byte and put into drive buffer.
OS fetches data from drive buffer.
Disk spins down to a stop.
OS returns 1 byte to your program.
```

In your program design, the above steps will be repeated 256 times.  With everybody's suggestion, the line marked with "-->" will read 256 bytes.  Thus the overhead is executed only once instead of 256 times to get the same quantity of data.

Comment: I've been told that OS actually does buffering. Anyway, if it doesn't I'm pretty sure that disc controller does a little bit of buffering.

Comment: Yes, but there is always the overhead instructions of calling the input function; maybe including reloading of the instruction cache.  To increase performance, this overhead should be reduced - therefore more data per request is more efficient.

Comment: What happens if the file is only 255 bytes and you try to read 256 bytes? Can you just loop over `bytes_read` to read the whole file?

Comment: If you ask for 256 bytes but there are only 253 bytes, the `fread` function will return 253.  You can read multiple *blocks* until the entire file is read; this is an ancient art due to restricted small memory sizes.  If you are reading from a file, I recommend multiples of 512 or 1024 as that is the size of a sector.

Answer (score 16):

In your code you are trying to read 256 bytes to the address of one int. If you want to read one byte at a time, call `fread(&buffer, 1, 1, file);` (See [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/)).

But a simpler solution will be to declare an array of bytes, read it all together and process it after that.

Comment: buffer is of type unsigned int. Not-initialized and so after your `fread(&buffer, 1, 1, file);` you will get a number where 24 bits will contain some random value.

Comment: How do you declare an array of bytes and read it all together? Thanks!

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - see the answer below mine :)

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned char buffer; // note: 1 byte
fread(&buffer, 1, 1, file);
```

It is time to read mans I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems with the code as it stands.

The prototype for fread is:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

You've set the size to 256 (bytes) and the count to 1. That's fine, that means "read one lump of 256 bytes, shove it into the buffer".

However, your buffer is on the order of 2-8 bytes long (or, at least, vastly smaller than 256 bytes), so you have a buffer overrun. You probably want to use fred(&buffer, 1, 1, file).

Furthermore, you're writing byte data to an int pointer. This will work on one endian-ness (small-endian, in fact), so you'll be fine on Intel architecture and from that learn bad habits tha WILL come back and bite you, one of these days.

Try real hard to only write byte data into byte-organised storage, rather than into ints or floats.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read 256 bytes into a 4-byte integer variable called "buffer".  You are overwriting the next 252 bytes of other data.

It seems like `buffer` should either be `unsigned char buffer[256];` or you should be doing `fread(&buffer, 1, 1, f)` and in that case `buffer` should be `unsigned char buffer;`.

Alternatively, if you just want a single character, you could just leave `buffer` as `int` (*unsigned* is not needed because C99 guarantees a reasonable minimum range for plain int) and simply say:

```
buffer = fgetc(f);
```